# More control over XlFind

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I'm using a script to allow users to find a serialnumber in a column of an excel sheet. A problem however is the flexibility of the search.

The serialnumbers may occur as the following examples: "12345678      ", "1 345678        ", "12 345678    " as you see, there are a varying number of spaces after the numbers which are causing problems. Additionally, the first two (or occasionally single) digits show the year of the serial number, and may or may not be separated by a space.

Is there any way to account for these variations without having to perform multiple searches or adjust the data?

```
Private Function ExcelFind(r As Excel.Range, s As String)
    Dim currentFind As Excel.Range = Nothing
    currentFind = r.Find(s, ,
Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, False)

    If currentFind IsNot Nothing Then
        Debug.Print("foundrow " & currentFind.Row)
        Debug.Print("foundcol " & currentFind.Column)
        Return (currentFind)
    Else
        Debug.Print("not found (EF1)")
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: `Range.Find` does support wildcards in the search value, e.g. `*123*` would find `2017   1230993`. As far as the spaces go, you could do a trim + substitute construction to get rid of those.

Comment: Not sure I understand your additionally comment  ... is the format of the serial number YYWWxxxx ?

Comment: The wildcards look useful, but I know that this will cause false positives to show up for instance when looking for "16 1234567*" when a "16 12345678" exists. Hoping for a way to ignore those trailing spaces but still look for an exact match otherwise. Can trim+substitute be used on the Range?

Comment: Well yes, however you'd have to change the values in the cells then. The alternative is to dump everything from `r` in an array, get rid of the spaces there, and loop over it to find your exact value.

Comment: So if  `s="1345678"` then you want to search for that number in the worksheet? and `"1345678"` can be present as `"1 345678"` or `"1 34 5678" or `"1 34567 8"`? Also will there be only one number in a cell or there can be multiple numbers?

Comment: @SiddharthRout The number can be present as one or two digits for the year, a space or not a space, and then the rest of the numbers without any interruptions, ending with a varying number of trailing spaces.

Comment: so if the number is `"1345678"` then it can be present as `"1 345678"` or `"13 45678"` or `"1345678     "`?

Comment: help me clarrify something ... is s the variable that may contain blank spaces or is it the column thay you are searching that has the blank spaces? Also ... I might have an aswer for the Additionally question ... but I need to understand this ... is the serial number format suppose to be YYWWxxxx but sometimes it comes as YWWxxxx if the year starts with a 0 digit like 01? and if the serial number is YYWWxxxx is it always that length?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes that is correct.

Comment: @MikePowell The column has blank spaces. The variable entered by the user is easy to remove or add spaces to as needed. The format comes in all the different forms but there is no set length. The year doesn't have anything to do with it, older numbers have a varying format due to negligence

Comment: Then search each number 3 times "1 345678","13 45678","1345678" using xlPart?

Comment: That would triple the search time though...

Comment: yup but that is much better than looping through each cell?

Comment: and it is not going to be 3 times always :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, an approach using an array to check against - This will be a lot faster than checking against each cell with as in Maddy Nikam's answer.
I did a run against A1:AN10000 and that took around 3 seconds. Still not optimal, but more workable than checking against the full range cell by cell.

```
Sub test(r As Excel.Range, s As String)
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim cl as long
Dim rw as long

arr = r.value

cl = 1
Do While cl <= r.Columns.Count
    rw = 1
    Do While rw <= r.Rows.Count
        arr(rw, cl) = Replace(arr(rw, cl), " ", "")
        If arr(rw, cl) = s Then
            Debug.Print r.Cells(rw, cl).Address
        End If
        rw = rw + 1
    Loop
    cl = cl + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

**Edit:** I'm assuming `r` will be a continuous range with this approach. If it's not you'll run into trouble with the addresses. 
For example calling this with `Set rng = Union(Range("A1:A3"), Range("B5:B7"))` and passing `rng` to `r`, the only found addresses by `Debug.Print` will be A1:A3, whereas a `Debug.Print(rng.Address)` will tell you $A$1:$A$3,$B$5:$B$7

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
    For Each cell In Rng
    Str = cell.Value
    Str = Replace(Str, " ", "")
        If s = Str Then
            Debug.Print ("foundrow " & cell.Row)
            Debug.Print ("foundcol " & cell.Column)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I did it this way before I found the excelfind function, sadly this takes much longer to complete. This is an issue since the range is several thousands of rows long.

Comment: Would work perfectly - Only performance is an issue if `r` has thousands of cells in it.

Comment: @Zyzyx ..You can create additional column which can have these serialnumbers without spaces.

Comment: you could also do     r.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart

Answer (score -1):

insert

```
s = Replace(s, " ", "")
```

before you look for it. This removes any blanks from variable s

Comment: `s` is the string to search for. The problem is in the range he's looking at.

Comment: No it's not ... the problem is that spaces can be introduced at either end or in the middle

Comment: `currentFind = r.Find(s, ...` - this means that `s` is the Search value. This has nothing to do with spaces in `s`, but with spaces in the cell values that are part of `r`.

Comment: Not true ... s is the search value ... removing false spaces from this search value is the only reasonable answer

Comment: Sorry Rik, I got it backward, you are correct ... it's the search column that has the blanks ... again my appologies

Comment: No worries, happens.